# Cookie not sending with request.js

Tags: node.js, cookies, request

So I had a API up and running however I decided to switch from using [nano](https://github.com/dscape/nano) to just using [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request). However I for some reason can't seem to get the cookie to send back to the server now. Here's an example of the code I've been testing.

```
var request = require('request')
var cookieJar = request.jar();
var myCookie;

request({
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/_session',
    form: {
        name: 'test',
        password: 'test123'
    }

},
function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) { console.log(err) };

    console.log(res.statusCode);
    console.log(res.headers);
    console.log(body);

    myCookie = request.cookie(res.headers['set-cookie'][0]);

    cookieJar.setCookie(myCookie, 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/_session');


});

request({
    method: 'GET',
    uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/db',
    jar: cookieJar
},
function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) { console.log(err) };

    console.log(cookieJar);
    console.log(res.statusCode);
    console.log(res.headers);
    console.log(body);
});
```

As you can see I'm able to get and set the cookie however I'm not authorized on the GET request. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Requests are asynchronous, so your two requests are made at the same time (before your cookieJar is set up). Try this instead:

```
var request = require('request')

request({
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/_session',
    form: {
        name: 'test',
        password: 'test123'
    }

},
function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err) };

    console.log(res.statusCode);
    console.log(res.headers);
    console.log(body);

    var myCookie = request.cookie(res.headers['set-cookie'][0]);

    var cookieJar = request.jar();
    cookieJar.setCookie(myCookie, 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/_session');

    request({
        method: 'GET',
        uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/db',
        jar: cookieJar
    },
    function(err, res, body) {
        if (err) { return console.log(err) };

        console.log(cookieJar);
        console.log(res.statusCode);
        console.log(res.headers);
        console.log(body);
    });
});
```