# How to deal with Sessions in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies

I'm trying to use a Website within node.js. Unfortunately the Site is telling me to enable the save of Session-Cookies. I tried to define a cookie-jar but i had no luck with it.

Simplified version of the code causing the problem:

```
var request = require('request');
var j = request.jar();
request.defaults({jar: j});
request({
    "uri": "https://www.somesite.tld",
    "method": "GET"
},function(error, response, body) {
    request({
        "uri": "https://www.somesite.tld/login",
        "method": "POST",
        "form": {
            "user": "Username",
            "pwd": "password"
        }
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your cookies to the cookie jar (at some point) before making the request. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23728945/cookie-not-sending-with-request-js/23728996#23728996) for a similar example.

Comment: TY for your answer. From what I'vre read in the specs I thought that it would add cookies from responses automatically when the requst has a jar specified. I switched to unirest by now. :)